# Macports Installation required

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, macports

I am planning to upgrade my OSx to latest version. I just wanted to ask that will i be required to install Macports again ? Or upgrading it simply will make it work accordingly with the new OSx. My current OSx is 10.9.4 and i am upgrading to the latest one.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @AndréKool The problem is that macports centres around Xcode and friends to build the ports (certainly for non-released versions of OSX), so it's not so black and white.

Answer (score 2):

Your MacPorts installation will *not* just work after a system upgrade. You need to follow the instructions in the [MacPorts Migration Guide](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).